# Pyspark: SaveTable in windows cannot handle windows path

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to save a  CSV file using a windows path (with "" instead of "/"). I think it does not works, because of the windows path.

1. Is this the problem why the code does not works?
2. Is there a workaround for the problem?

The code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row

def init_spark(appname):
  spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(appname).getOrCreate()
  sc = spark.sparkContext
  return spark,sc

def run_on_configs_spark():
  spark,sc = init_spark(appname="bucket_analysis")
  p_configs_RDD = sc.parallelize([1,4,5])
  p_configs_RDD=p_configs_RDD.map(mul)
  schema = StructType([StructField('a', IntegerType()), StructField('b', IntegerType())])
  df=spark.createDataFrame(p_configs_RDD,schema)
  df.write.saveAsTable(r"C:\Users\yuvalr\Desktop\example_csv",format="csv")


def mul(x):
  return (x,x**2)

run_on_configs_spark()
```

The error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yuvalr/Desktop/Git_folder/algo_sim/Bucket_analysis/Set_multiple_configurations/run_multiple_configurations.py", line 426, in <module>
    analysis()
  File "C:/Users/yuvalr/Desktop/Git_folder/algo_sim/Bucket_analysis/Set_multiple_configurations/run_multiple_configurations.py", line 408, in analysis
    run_CDH()
  File "C:/Users/yuvalr/Desktop/Git_folder/algo_sim/Bucket_analysis/Set_multiple_configurations/run_multiple_configurations.py", line 420, in run_CDH
    max_prob_for_extension=None, max_base_size_B=4096,OP_arr=[0.2],
  File "C:/Users/yuvalr/Desktop/Git_folder/algo_sim/Bucket_analysis/Set_multiple_configurations/run_multiple_configurations.py", line 173, in settings_print
    dic=get_map_of_worst_seq(params)
  File "C:/Users/yuvalr/Desktop/Git_folder/algo_sim/Bucket_analysis/Set_multiple_configurations/run_multiple_configurations.py", line 245, in get_map_of_worst_seq
    run_over_settings_spark_test(info_obj)
  File "C:/Users/yuvalr/Desktop/Git_folder/algo_sim/Bucket_analysis/Set_multiple_configurations/run_multiple_configurations.py", line 239, in run_over_settings_spark_test
    run_on_configs_spark(configs)
  File "C:\Users\yuvalr\Desktop\Git_folder\algo_sim\Bucket_analysis\Set_multiple_configurations\spark_parallelized_configs.py", line 17, in run_on_configs_spark
    df.write.saveAsTable(r"C:\Users\yuvalr\Desktop\example_csv",format="csv")
  File "C:\Users\yuvalr\Desktop\spark\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 868, in saveAsTable
    self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)
  File "C:\Users\yuvalr\venv\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "C:\Users\yuvalr\Desktop\spark\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 137, in deco
    raise_from(converted)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: 
mismatched input ':' expecting {<EOF>, '.', '-'}(line 1, pos 1)

== SQL ==
C:\Users\yuvalr\Desktop\example_csv
-^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it the problem is with your output line:

Try this instead:

```py
df.write.csv("file:///C:/Users/yuvalr/Desktop/example_csv.csv")
```

- Yes, I know you're on Windows so *you're* expecting backslashes, but PySpark isn't
- Windows is very sensitive to file extensions - without the `.csv`, you'll probably just make a folder called `example_csv`
- You don't need a Regex `r""` string for this
- Using the `file:///` doubly-confirms that this is a file we're talking about

Comment: To prevent confusion, he certainly needed an `r""` string for allowing his single `"\"` characters (or double them), but indeed, with forward slashes this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see `saveAsTable()` expects a `tablename` to be provided which can written in
directory `spark.sql.warehouse.dir`

> saveAsTable(name, format=None, mode=None, partitionBy=None, **options)

**Parameters**

- name – **the table name**
- format – the format used to save
- mode – one of append, overwrite, error, errorifexists, ignore (default: error)
- partitionBy – names of partitioning columns
- options – all other string options

Source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter

Workaround: (mind for windows `C:\\`)

set spark.sql.warehouse.dir pointing to destination directory as below

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row

def init_spark(appname):
  spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:\\Users\yuvalr\Desktop")\
    .appName(appname).getOrCreate()
  sc = spark.sparkContext
  return spark,sc

def run_on_configs_spark():
  spark,sc = init_spark(appname="bucket_analysis")
  p_configs_RDD = sc.parallelize([1,4,5])
  p_configs_RDD=p_configs_RDD.map(mul)
  schema = StructType([StructField('a', IntegerType()), StructField('b', IntegerType())])
  df=spark.createDataFrame(p_configs_RDD,schema)
  df.write.saveAsTable("example_csv",format="csv",mode="overwrite")


def mul(x):
  return (x,x**2)

run_on_configs_spark()
```

Edit 1:
If it is an external table (external path where underlying file is stored), you can use below

```
#df.write.option("path","C:\\Users\yuvalr\Desktop").saveAsTable("example_csv",format="csv",mode="overwrite")


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row


def init_spark(appname):
  spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName(appname).getOrCreate()
  sc = spark.sparkContext
  return spark,sc

def run_on_configs_spark():
  spark,sc = init_spark(appname="bucket_analysis")
  p_configs_RDD = sc.parallelize([1,4,5])
  p_configs_RDD=p_configs_RDD.map(mul)
  schema = StructType([StructField('a', IntegerType()), StructField('b', IntegerType())])
  df=spark.createDataFrame(p_configs_RDD,schema)
  df.write.option("path","C:\\Users\yuvalr\Desktop").saveAsTable("example_csv",format="csv",mode="overwrite")


def mul(x):
  return (x,x**2)

run_on_configs_spark()
```